# Правильно ли я расставил запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

Её цель показать Вам каким легким может быть сотрудничество с ведущим. Выражаю благодарность Виктору и Анастасии Шукмановым за участие, ресторану Анданте по адресу Мытнинская набережная дом 3, в лице Игнатенковой Натальи за предоставленную площадку, и фотографу Дмитрию Модестову за проделаную работу.

Comment: См. также: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/445378/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%83%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%83%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%b9

Answer (score 1):

Мой вариант слегка изменённого текста.

> Её цель — показать Вам, каким легким может быть сотрудничество с
>   ведущим. Выражаю благодарность Виктору и Анастасии Шукмановым за
>   участие, ресторану Анданте (Мытнинская набережная, дом 3) в лице
>   Игнатенковой Натальи за предоставленную площадку, а также фотографу
>   Дмитрию Модестову за проделанную работу.

Обязательные изменения:
запятая в первом предложении перед "каким";
в слове "проделанную" два -н-.

Comment: А между _цель_ и _показать_ не следует ли поставить тире? Как считаете?

Comment: @СтепанПопов Конечно. Спасибо!

Comment: Grizzly, благодарю Вас.

Comment: А что насчет ресторана "Анданте"? Может, стоит заключить в кавычки? (Вы только не подумайте, что я тут с каким-то ироническим тоном, просто самому интересно.)

Comment: @СтепанПопов А вот здесь я не уверен. В обычной деловой переписке (не в документах) чаще названия организаций пишут без кавычек, а с кавычками это уже вроде как официоз. Я думал над этим, но решил оставить авторский вариант написания.

Comment: @grizzly Да, согласен с вами.

Comment: @СтепанПопов Я и против иронии ничего не имею :)

Comment: Кавычки нужно поставить, это название предприятия общественного питания. Заключаются в кавычки "названия организаций, учреждений, предприятий, акционерных обществ, фирм и т. д." http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/75-kav2

Comment: А разве убрать запятую перед *в лице* не относится к обязательным изменениям?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Вот что имелось в виду: текст нуждается в стилистической правке, поэтому я указал в качестве обязательных те исправления, которые будут необходимы при любой редактуре. Если обратили внимание, там я внёс ещё много правок, каждая из которых в каком-то смысле обязательна.